# Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have 2 tables: admin_user and admin_account.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var admin_user = sequelize.define('admin_user', {
    id: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        isEmail: true,
      }
    },
    user_name:{
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    }
  });

  admin_user.associate = (models) =>{
    admin_user.hasOne(models.admin_account, { foreignKey: 'admin_user_id' });
  };

  return admin_user;
};


'use strict';
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var admin_account = sequelize.define('admin_account', {
    admin_user_id:{
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    password: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
  });
  return admin_account;
};
```

and getting this error while creating the table:

Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin_users` (`id` INTEGER auto_increment , `name` VARCHAR(255), `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE, `user_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `admin_users` FROM `milkman_prod1`
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin_accounts` (`admin_user_id` INTEGER , `password` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`admin_user_id`), FOREIGN KEY (`admin_user_id`) REFERENCES `admin_users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB;
**Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Cannot add foreign key constraint**

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this code:

```
    'use strict';
    const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
      var admin_account = sequelize.define('admin_user', {
        admin_user_id:{
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          primaryKey: true
        },
        password: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING
        }
      });
admin_account.associate = (models) =>{
    admin_account.belongsTo(models.admin_user);
  };
      return admin_account;
    };
```

Comment: Thanks Riajul. It will eliminate the error but nothing will be entered in the table. I came up with another solution:



admin_user.associate = (models) =>{
    admin_user.hasOne(models.admin_account, { foreignKey: { name: 'admin_user_id', allowNull: false }, onDelete: 'restrict', onUpdate: 'restrict' });
  };